# How to open a new Window from an other class in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I'm still learning how to do C# applications and I have actually a problem with a window.

I've created a WPF project and I've separated some part of my main window in sub-parts (user-controls) so I can have a cleaner `xaml` code to work with.
I have a lot of different UserControl such as `UserControlMenuStrip`. All of them are inside the `MainWindow`.

Inside the MenuStrip was a MenuItem called `Parameters` :

```
<MenuItem Header="_Parameters" x:Name="MenuParameters"/>
```

I have created a new window called `ParametersWindow`. My goal was to open a child window centered with the main window when I click on the item.

But I don't really know how to proceed? Should I make a `click=` event and write down the code inside the linked `UserControlMenuItem.xaml.cs` linked file? Or in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file? Or maybe a new and clean file?

When I try to put it inside `UserControlMenuItem.xaml.cs`, I can't properly set the owner of the window I create this method but I can't set the owner:

```
private void OpenParametersWindow()
        {
            WindowParameters WinParam = new WindowParameters();
            WinParam.Owner = MainWindow();
            WinParam.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            WinParam.Show();
        }
```

And, when I try via the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I can't even get the variable...

So... How can I properly open the Window properly? And should I do it in the `xaml.cs` file or create a new one for a better understanding?

Comment: Seems like you are visiting StackOverflow but not looking for this topic anymore. I've added a solution hope you see it.

Answer (score 1):

**I've Created a class and added a static field as MainWindow to holding reference**

```
class ReferenceClass
{
    public static MainWindow mainWindow = null;//firstly null.we will set it in WindowLoaded event.
}
```

You can create a class like this for accessing reference of your MainWindow from wherever you want.Give your MainWindow reference to its static field.

**MainWindow Loaded Event**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReferenceClass.mainWindow = this; //setting the reference to static field of ReferenceClass.
}
```

**Menu Click (Event called on MenuStrip UserControl)**

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewWindow nw = new NewWindow();
    nw.Owner = ReferenceClass.mainWindow;//Calling the reference of MainWindow from our class.
    nw.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    nw.Show();
}
```

**Here we go**

[image]

**Project**

[image]

This is **just a way** for solving this issue.We can find more solutions which are better than mine but i use this solution when i need.

Answer (score 0):

A handle to the parent window for any usercontrol can be obtained that way:

```
Window wndParent = System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(this);
WinParam.Show(wndParent);
```

But when working with WPF, it is more convenient to use the MVVM pattern

Answer (score -1):

As you writing UI in WPF it is preferred to implement it with MVVM pattern. It allows you to have a clear separation of concerns between code and presentation.
Regarding your question about how to set `Owner` I suggest reading this series of articles about dialogs in WPF implemented with MVVM in mind

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dialogs-in-wpf-mvvm/